# Invoking an exe from Javascript with Arguments

Tags: javascript, activex, jscript

I'm trying to invoke cmd.exe from JavaScript with arguments. But it is opening *cmd.exe* and doing nothing.

Below is the script.

```
function f_InvokeEXE() {
        var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
        var commandtoRun = '"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"';
        var argumentString = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PICT\\pict.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PICT\\Sample.txt" > "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PICT\\pab.xls"';
        var a = oShell.run(commandtoRun + ' ' + argumentString, 1, true);
    }
```

Its working fine when manually doing that. (opening command prompt and entering that command).

Comment: I assume you're doing this in Internet Explorer (the only thing that supports `ActiveXObject`)

Comment: you need to use the `/c` arg for cmd.exe. without that, it wno't execute whatever you're passing in on the command line.

Comment: Do you need cmd.exe at all? Doesn't `WScript.shell` allow to run `pict.exe` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `/c` arg for cmd.exe. Without that, it will NOT execute your command string:

```
C:\Users\marc>cmd echo foo
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\marc>exit

C:\Users\marc>cmd /c echo foo
foo

C:\Users\marc>
```

Note how the version WITHOUT `/c` just starts up a NEW shell.

Comment: could you please modify the function I posted as per your answer and repost it? var argumentString = 'cmd /c notepad.exe' is working but var argumentString = 'cmd /c  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PICT\\pict.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PICT\\Sample.txt" > "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PICT\\pab.xls"' is giving error as "C:\Program" is not recognized as internal or external command